# Connection to database failed! Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, sockets, ubuntu-12.04

Hello i been running into this error after moving my website to a new host
[DonationSystem] Connection to database failed! Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

I am running on the same version of linux ub 12.04 the server one.

i have a few databases running that are working such as my phpbb one.

i have tried link them edit configs and everything else the internet has told me even removed mysql and reinstalled it so any ideas?

oh and the database is local and im using localhost and root is the user

Comment: The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting-disconnecting.html) states that your server is not running: *If, when you attempt to log in, you get an error message such as ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2), it means that the MySQL server daemon (Unix) or service (Windows) is not running.* Have a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/395208/how-to-start-mysql-server-in-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: im sure that my server is running since my fourm board is working as i said above.... http://mc-builds.com/forums/